# Counting clicks when pressing a button + save them in a .txt file

Tags: php, jquery

I want to make a code that when someone presses a button like: "Click me" it will count as a click and it will save on the .txt

```
<?php

if (file_exists('count_file.txt')) 
{
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', r);
    $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count_file.txt')); 
    echo $dat+1;
    fclose($fil);
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
}

else
{
    $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
    fwrite($fil, 1);
    echo '1';
    fclose($fil);
}
?>
```

I used that script but I want that it only works with nclick="javascript:countClicks(); so not when you refresh the page or something

How can I get this working?

Comment: You have mentioned that you used that script. Which script you used ? Can you post here ?

Comment: Where's your javascript code?

Comment: I hope you have added the shared script inside your page where 'click me' button exists as a include file so it executes when you refresh. Try to use ajax inside countClicks() function and refer to the above script as the ajax URL.

Comment: Please see my answer on the other question, it is the correct way to count clicks / page views by acquiring a lock on the file using `flock`

Comment: cmorrissey, and how can I get it working for only a button?

Comment: @Svennohz see my answer ;)

Comment: Not working for me @TechJS

Comment: @Svennohz assuming you have a button like this: `<button id="mybutton">Click Me</button>` then the code should work.

Comment: @TechJS It doesn't display the count on my page.

Answer (score -1):

thats so simple.
assuming you have a button like this:

```
<button id="mybutton">Click Me</button>
```

then this goes to that page:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementById('myFrm').submit();
});
</script>
<form id="myFrm" method="post" action="file.php"><input type="hidden" name="doit" value="true" /></form>
```

or if you want to send without changing the page:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('mybutton').addEventListener('click', function(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","file.php",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("doit=true");
});
</script>
```

in `file.php`:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($_POST) && array_key_exists('doit', $_POST)) {
        if($_POST['doit'] == "true") {
            if (file_exists('count_file.txt')) 
            {
                $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', r);
                $dat = fread($fil, filesize('count_file.txt')); 
                echo $dat+1;
                fclose($fil);
                $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
                fwrite($fil, $dat+1);
            }

            else
            {
                $fil = fopen('count_file.txt', w);
                fwrite($fil, 1);
                echo '1';
                fclose($fil);
            }
        }
    }
?>
```